# Running a trigger in google apps script by clicking on a link which I can store in bookmarks?

Tags: google-apps-script

A script "SCRIPT" is attached to a spreadsheet "SPREADSHEET".
Is it possible to create a link for the "trigger to SCRIPT", so that I can store the link somewhere such as in bookmarks, and run the script just by clicking on the link?

Comment: You can create a function with the `doGet()` reserved function name in your project, and publish the project as a Web App.  A link *is* a GET request.  When you click the link, a GET request will be made to the published URL of the Web App.  Then the `doGet()` function will run.  The GET request is the "event" and the doGet() function is triggered by the GET request event.  `doGet()` "listens" for the GET request to be made.  You can pass information to the `doGet(e)` function by adding an "event" parameter in the parenthesis.  Typically the letter "e" is used, but any letter can be used.

Comment: [documentation of Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)